# Item type in menu of Applications: "Application" or "Application in Terminal"?

Tags: launcher, appmenu

I was wondering what is the difference between the two item type in menu of Applications: "Application" and "Application in Terminal"?

What kinds of applications are specified as "Application" and what kinds for "Application in Terminal"?

This question is motivated from [my previous one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26720/add-matlab-to-main-menu).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application is something with separate UI, for example calculator or GIMP.

Application in Terminal is command line software, that should run inside of terminal emulator. Otherwise you can't interact with it.

Basically, select Applucation for software with graphical user interface and Application in Terminal for command line utilities and scripts.

You can test this with 'top', for example, create shortcut with and without terminal, and you can see the difference.

Comment: Thanks! But why I cannot  specify Application type for the GUI version of my Matlab, but have to choose Application in Terminal for it? See my linked post http://askubuntu.com/questions/26720/add-matlab-to-main-menu .

Comment: What is the difference exactly? If I run `smplayer %U` in a terminal I get the same thing as the launcher only the theme is different. If I run `gedit %U` all the preferences are borked.  Put another way, is it possible to replicate "Application" in the terminal? Looking at a .desktop file it says `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` at the beginning, but placing that before a command just opens the argument with a default application. Honestly I find this launcher business the most confusing aspect of running Ubuntu.