# Installing MATLAB and its launcher icon

Tags: installation, launcher, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Matlab to main menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26720/add-matlab-to-main-menu)

Hello,

I am trying to install MATLAB.  I got it installed, but I am having a hard time getting the launcher icon to work using the instructions from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB/R2010a).  I get a icon in my Applications > Programming taskbar but when I click the Matlab launcher icon, it gives me an error saying:

```
Could not launch 'MATLAB R2010a'
Failed to execute child process
"matlab" (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix this?  As an alternative route, is there another way to launch matlab without the MATLAB launcher icon?

Thanks! :)

Comment: for launch, try typing `matlab` in terminal. use tab to see if there is any autocomplete.

Comment: nope, does not work...

Answer (score 2):

As you said typing `matlab` doesn't work. I use it this way:

1. change to MATLAB current folder

   ```
   cd Documents/MATLAB
   ```
2. then, where I have my MATLAB installed:

   ```
   sh
   /home/my_name/Applications/R2010a/bin/matlab
   ```

Comment: Ah, I see the matlab file.  This works executing the Matlab program.  Now if only I can get that launcher icon to work... Don't know if you have any ideas to get that to work, do you? :)  Thanks, nevertheless.

Comment: Unfortunately, even I don't know how to get the launcher to work. I tried using 'Edit Menus' and adding 'New Item' to menu but even with the same command as given above it didn't work for me. I tried removing `sh` but no luck! So I use the method shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in launcher:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2010a/bin/matlab -desktop
```

(or just change the root to your installation folder and put `/matlab -desktop`)

you can read more information here:

[Add Matlab to main menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26720/add-matlab-to-main-menu/29094#29094)