# Matlab launcher doesn't work

Tags: matlab

I've installed Matlab R2011a on ubuntu12.04. I've installed it in a folder I've created in the Home Folder.
I can run it if I run the code
    cd directory
    ./matlab

However I want to create a launcher that runs. I've followed the steps as explained in the guide here, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB, even tho it's for ubuntu 10.04, and the launcher appeared.
However when I press it nothing happens.
I'm not sure what I should do next...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`matlab.desktop` file you downloaded and put in `/usr/share/applications/` says:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/matlab.png
Name=MATLAB R2011a
Comment=Start MATLAB - The Language of Technical Computing
Exec=matlab -desktop
Categories=Development;
```

I think you should change the `Exec` line with your installation folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've just installed Matlab 2012b on Ubuntu 12.10 and followed up by installing the *matlab-support* package in the Ubuntu Software Centre:

`sudo apt-get install matlab-support`

(As per this answer in a related question: https://askubuntu.com/a/140078/16835)

Answer (score 0):

You could put a symlink to the matlab binary in your ~/bin directory. Create the dir if you haven't already. /home/you/bin should be in your path (`$ echo $PATH`).