# How can I launch MATLAB 2012?

Tags: command-line, matlab

I have a problem with the MATLAB 2012 installation.

After having installed it using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and having used `gksudo nautilus`, I have installed MATLAB in the correct folder, `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a`.

Then I inserted the license and the window told "activation complete" or something like that.

This made me happy, but only for a while because as soon as I try to search for MATLAB within the applications I cannot find it and neither if I try to run

```
matlab
```

into terminal it says:

```
command not found
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try navigating to `bin` folder in your Matlab installation directory:

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin
```

Then execute Matlab from there:

```
./matlab
```

Source: [How do I launch MATLAB on Linux?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-AT26VI/index.html?solution=1-AT26VI)

If that worked for you, you can create alias:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab matlab
```

This trick will allow you to launch matlab from any directory, as you were trying to do. Note that you should use `sudo` for the last command, since it creates alias globally, for all users.

If you are not in sudoers list (i.e. you cannot use `sudo` command), you can create alias locally. To do that, open `.bashrc` file, which is in your home directory:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line to the end of that file:

```
alias matlab="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab"
```

Finally, reopen your terminal, or type `source ~/.bashrc` and execute this command.

Source: [How do I create shortcuts, aliases, or links to MATLAB?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9A6FYK/index.html?solution=1-9A6FYK)

Comment: Thank you very much for the first part: Matlab now opens and it works from the folder where I installed it, anyway it fails to create the symbolic link since the terminal tells "permission denied"

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault. You should use sudo for the symbolic link creation command: "sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab matlab".

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Comprehensive answer. I like it.

Comment: Sorry but yesterday I didn't had connection to the web. Your answer was perfect for solving my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Now I can launch Matlab from terminal. But how do I create a shortcut on my dock? I tried to launch it first and then lock the icon, but clicking the icon won't launch Matlab again.

Answer (score 12):

I've just installed Matlab 2012b on Ubuntu 12.10 and followed up by installing the *matlab-support* package in the Ubuntu Software Centre:

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

(As per this answer in a related question: https://askubuntu.com/a/140078/16835)

Comment: by far the easiest solution! And quick, takes only 2 min to download and configure (and I'm using a 7 year old laptop so ...)