# How to register an application as installed in Ubuntu?

Tags: matlab

I have installed MATLAB in my Ubuntu. However, programs such as OpenCV can't be detected although they are installed and also files with the `*.m` extension are not associated with MATLAB. I also can't find MATLAB when I am trying to set default application in properties. I am using MATLAB with an academic license. When I try to run `matlab` in command line, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/matlab: 445: .: Can't open /usr/local/bin/util/arch.sh
```

How do I register MATLAB as installed software in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you looked at this already? With respect to the error you are getting, I would especially note step 5 in the installation instructions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB

Comment: As far as being able to associate `*.m`, you probably need to create a `matlab.desktop` file first. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139352/how-do-i-make-a-matlab-launcher-for-unity?rq=1

Comment: This may also help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/185763/how-can-i-launch-matlab-2012?rq=1