# modifying matlab symbolic link

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, matlab

I've successfully created a symbolic link to MATLAB as suggested in the questions below:
[How can I launch MATLAB 2012?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185763/how-can-i-launch-matlab-2012)

So I can run MATLAB from any directory. However, I've noticed that some people have an installation that instead of inputting in the command line:

```
$./matlab
```

They just put:

```
$matlab
```

and it runs. I would like to have the latter done. I am not quite sure how this is done, since MATLAB is an executable file and the terminal would have to automatically run it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shortcut to your `matlab` installation by doing :

```
sudo ln -s /<path-to-your-matlab>/matlab /usr/local/bin/matlab
```

For example if your `matlab` folder is in your `Download` folder, run :

```
sudo ln -s /home/Arturo/Download/matlab /usr/local/bin/matlab
```

---

Once you have created this shortcut, you will only need to type `matlab` in a terminal to open Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

create desktop launcher
and add **`-desktop`**

> matlab -desktop

~/.local/share/applications/matlab.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Matlab
Comment=matlab Matlab
Icon=~/programes/Matlab/R2021b/Matlab_Logo.png
TryExec=~/programes/Matlab/R2021b/bin/matlab
Exec=~/programes/Matlab/R2021b/bin/matlab -desktop
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=matlab
Categories=Math;Calc;Calculation;simulation;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

[reference](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/20-how-do-i-make-a-desktop-launcher-for-matlab-in-linux#answer_244181)