# Trouble running Matlab 2012a on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits

Tags: matlab

I just finished a Matlab 2012a installation that reported that the C compiler needs to be upgraded, but got stuck when I tried to click on the hyperlink provided by the installer to fix it. When trying the new installation I get this:

```
 sudo sh matlab
matlab: 1: /home/antonio/Matlab/bin/util/oscheck.sh: /lib64/libc.so.6: not found
```

Is this due to the compiler issue? How do I fix this?

Comment: On my system (12.04), libc is in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (which is a symlink to libc-2.15.so). On a different machine, which I cannot access right now, I had no trouble installing 64bit Matlab (no explicit compiler upgrade necessary). Are you running 64bit Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, the question says I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits (on the title)

Answer (score 1):

If something can't find `/lib64/libc.so.6` -- You might find `libc.so.6`:

```
locate libc.so.6 # You might also need to update locate's database first: sudo updatedb
```

This command will tell You where it is. After what You might link it where it is expected:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6
```

If `locate` can't find the file -- this probably means You don't have it. You can find out which package provides it with:

```
apt-file search libc.so.6 # You might need to run "sudo apt-file update" before that
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed Matlab 2012b on Ubuntu 12.10 and followed up by installing the matlab-support package in the Ubuntu Software Centre:

`sudo apt-get install matlab-support`

(As per this answer in a related question: https://askubuntu.com/a/140078/16835)

This will add a desktop icon/launcher, as well as allow you to fix the compiler linking problem.